# Using UnManaged C++ Dll in C#

Tags: marshalling

Hi this is my Function in C++ dll.
I am Trying to use it in My C#  Application. Have tried so many things but nothing seems to work for me.

```
xyz_API LONG __stdcall xyz_Login(char *dwIP,unsigned short dwPort,char *dwUseName,char 
*dwPassword,MyDetail dwInfo,char *dwInfo);

* Parameter:
```

[in]
    dwIP
    dwpPort
    dwUseName
     dwPassword
      [out]
        MyDetail (struct)

This is the Struct :

```
typedef struct
{
int         xyz_id;      
int         xyz_ch;     
int         xyz_total;   
int         my_id;          
char        my_Info[10];   
char        m_status;       
}MyDetail ,*MyDetail ;
```

I made a Class for this Struct in my code as:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class MyDetail 
    {

        public int xyz_id;
        public int xyz_ch;
       public int xyz_total;
        public int my_id;
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,
ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 10)]
  public char[] my_Info;
       public sbyte m_status;
}
```

I am using following line of code to do use it in C# application:

```
[DllImport("MYC.dll", EntryPoint = "xyz_Login", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int xyz_Login([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string dwIP,   ushort dwPort, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string dwUseName, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string dwPassword, MyDetail dwmyInfo, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string dwInfo);
```

My Form Calling:

```
MyDetail obj= new MyDetail();`enter code here`
int result = xyz_Login("192.168.1.10", 9001, "admin", "admin", obj, null);
```

code works perfectly but there is not output. MyDetail object always return null.
Is There a problem in marshalling. thanks in advance

Comment: The C++ function declaration is nonsense, do not pinvoke until you've tested it from a C++ test program first.

Comment: this is defined as :
#define  xyz_API __declspec(dllexport) 
then the declaration. this is a method on c++ application and the above declaration is in VC++ Application

Answer (score 0):

First, the C++ function:

```
  xyz_API LONG __stdcall xyz_Login(char *dwIP,unsigned short dwPort,char *dwUseName,char 
*dwPassword,MyDetail dwInfo,char *dwInfo);
```

The paramter "dwInfo" is a struct type, not a pointer or a reference type, so the parameter is passed by value, so in the function xyz_Login, you are modifying a local copy of the struct, no changes to the struct in C#. So you should change it: `MyDetail* dwInfo`

Meanwhile, you should change the dllimport in C# to:

[DllImport("MYC.dll", EntryPoint = "xyz_Login", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int xyz_Login(string dwIP,   ushort dwPort,  string dwUseName,  string dwPassword, ref MyDetail dwmyInfo, string dwInfo);

In a PInvoke call, a ref struct is translated into a pointer to the struct; also, char* is ansi, not unicode.

Comment: Thanks Matt,
but the above signature i got from a VC++ application which uses the same win32 DLL which i want to use.
     #define xyz_API __declspec(dllexport)
     xyz_API LONG __stdcall xyz_Login(char *dwIP,unsigned short  dwPort,char *dwUseName,char 
*dwPassword,MyDetail dwInfo,char *dwInfo);
..
Do we have any tool available to get the Signature of function in Unmanaged dll that would be useful.

Comment: Sorry Matt. I got a tool to translate the signature.it says the same you suggested. thanks for the info. i will write again if i need further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I got this running using following:
Struct As:

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
     public class MyDetail 
   {

    public int xyz_id;
    public int xyz_ch;
   public int xyz_total;
    public int my_id;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10)]
  public string my_Info;
   public sbyte m_status;
}
```

DLLImport Statement AS:

```
  [DllImport("MYC.dll", EntryPoint = "NET_DVR_Login")]
  public static extern Int32 xyz_Login(string dwIP, UInt16 dwPort, string  Name,string dwPassword, IntPtr myDetail, char[] info);
```